# Find single line files and move them to a subfolder

Tags: bash, file, grep, find

I am using the following bash line to find text files in a subfolder with a given a pattern inside it and move them to a subfolder:

```
find originalFolder/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -q 'mySpecificPattern' {} \; -exec mv -i {} destinationFolder/ \;
```

Now instead of grepping a pattern, I would like to move the files to a subfolder if they consist only of a single line (of text): how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
   [[ $(wc -l < "$file") -eq 1 ]] && echo mv -i "$file" destinationFolder/
done < <(find originalFolder/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

Note use of `echo` in front of `mv` so that you can verify output before actually executing `mv`. Once you're satisfied with output, remove `echo` before `mv`.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo that I have just fixed. Please try now.

Comment: Why am I getting this error in the third line now? `syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: @FrancescoBoi make sure you're using `bash` when using this script.

Answer (score 0):

Using `wc` as shown above is the most straightforward way, although it reads the entire file to determine the length.  It's also possible to do length checks with `awk`, and the `exit` function lets you fit that into a find command.

```
find . -type f -exec awk 'END { exit (NR==1 ? 0 : 1) } NR==2 { exit 1 }' {} \; -print
```

The command returns status 0 if there has been only 1 input record at end-of-file, and it also exits immediately with status 1 when line 2 is encountered; this should easily outrun `wc` if large files are a performance concern.